# You are waking up the whole house

Tags: meaning, phrases

My wife used the expression "you are waking up the house" when my son was making a lot of noise. Now that is actually wrong, I think - that would imply that the house as an entity was being woken, which is wrong as the house is brick.

However, "you are waking up the entire house" is acceptable in British English. So why does adding "Whole" change the meaning so much?

My only thought was that it could be a corruption of "Household". Any thoughts?

[edit] Just for clarification, I do understand that "waking up the house" carries the same meaning, but the interest was that the normal usage is the whole house. And I am interested in why this "whole" makes a difference.

Comment: I think this is just peeving.

Comment: Interestingly, the literal translation of "You are waking up the whole house" is also common in German: "Du weckst das ganze Haus auf": [http://www.google.de/search?num=20&hl=de&q=Du+weckst+das+ganze+Haus+auf&btnG=Google-Suche&sourceid=Mozilla-search&start=0#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&source=hp&q=%22Du+weckst+das+ganze+Haus+auf%22&pbx=1&oq=%22Du+weckst+das+ganze+Haus+auf%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5044l5865l0l6498l2l2l0l0l0l0l137l224l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c11a03b68aa6&biw=1280&bih=815](Google.de)

Comment: It's the common idiom. No one (save you) could ever think it means to arouse every brick and batten. I hope you didn't lay any constructive criticism on your wife about her "mistake".

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with interpreting this as making so much noise that the house (which might be thought of as in eternal slumber) was roused from its rest due to the incredible noise that the person was making.

Comment: In my experience (American English), "whole house" is more common and "entire house" would mean exactly the same thing -- everyone in the house(hold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have thought *whole house* or *entire house* was more usual than *house* on its own in that context, but the etymology of *whole* is quite unrelated to that of *household*. The appeal of *whole house* may lie in the alliteration.

Comment: Which is the sound that is alliterated ?

Comment: @speedyGonzales: /h/.

Comment: @speedyGonzales: **wh**ole **h**ouse. I will admit to having heard this expression with an adjective for house that destroys the alliteration, though.

Comment: I doubt that alliteration plays into it. See the example in @tenfour's answer on my comment.

Comment: You are getting the accept because the alliterative answer is probably close to the reason for using it.

Answer (score 18):

It means "all the people within the house". Here, "house" is being used [metonymically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) to describe a set of people (the inhabitants).

Comment: Yes, metonymy. "The pen is mightier than the sword", and all that.

Comment: But who "whole" as the modifier to make it "the people in the house" rather than "the bricks and mortar"? That is what puzzles me.

Comment: @Schroedinger Why would it ever refer to the bricks and mortar?

Comment: "Jim ate 4 cookies. Susan ate the whole box"  -- obviously "box" refers to its contents, not the cardboard packaging.

Comment: @tenfour: I don't think it would be extreme to expect that the OP _would_ think it refers to the cardboard.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, RegDwight! That's much more accurate. Anyway for the OP, 'whole' is just an intensifier, but it gives a bit of a clue to the metonymic usage as well... "the whole <container>" is sort of a set phrase.

Comment: @tenfour "Jim ate four cookies, Susan ate the box" has a much different feel to it, which I think is Schroedingers Cat's point.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be interpreted either as "the household" OR the "the house as an entity in itself".  As support for the second intepretation, consider "you're making enough noise to wake the dead".  Obviously you can't literally make enough noise to wake the dead (you could make enough noise to make the living dead, but that's a separate issue), so there's a bit of hyerpbole invlolved, but it does make sense...